# How do i create make the allow/deny firewall rule conditional in terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-template-file

I have a firewall rule in my GCP project and the values are read from variables at run time, it works successfully however i now have a use case where i want to add a deny block instead of allow. You cannot have both in there, is there a way to have the allow block be replaced by a deny block based on a condition.

Perhaps if the variable name is X, then use a deny block, or else use allow block.  See sample code below.

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "fw" {
 ....
  allow {
    protocol    = var.somevariable[element(keys(var.somevariable), count.index)]["protocol"]
    ports       = var.somevariable[element(keys(var.somevariable), count.index)]["ports"]
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a job for what they call [**dynamic blocks**](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html)

In short: I see it as having **two** dynamic blocks, one for allow and one for deny. Each of them would use some conditions (might be mutually exclusive). A stub of your code could be:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "fw" {
  dynamic "allow" {
    for_each = var.allow_entries
    ...
  }
  dynamic "block" {
    for_each = var.block_entries
    ...
  }
}
```